# Azure AD B2C not rendering newly added field (type: TextBox) in the UI

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

any help is appreciated.

I am using the below technical profile for validating user login.
I have added a new field "field3" as an outputClaim.
The field3 claimType is also added below.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">False</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">False</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="field3" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

```
<ClaimType Id="field3">
    <DisplayName>field 3</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>new text field</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>
```

I am hoping to see the field3 as a textField in the Login UI.
But its not appearing in the UI.
But on click of button login, its validating for field3 and throws an error. "field3 is required"

[image]

What should be done for field3 to be rendered in the UI?

Comment: is the `ClaimType id="field3"` in the same xml file that the other 2 (email and password) are in?

Comment: @MarkC. yes they are in different files.

Answer (score 0):

The self-asserted-technical-profile should be connected to below dataUri in contentDefinition

```
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.7</DataUri>
```

I was doing it wrong. accidently connected it to a different dataUri

The issue is solved.